# set http headers on salesforce site (x-frame)

Tags: force.com-sites, security

I'd like to be able to prevent an externally-facing force.com site from being iframed.  I don't know how to do this on a force.com site of visualforce pages.

I know that I can put "clickjack protection" on, but as many people have found, that breaks all use of inline visualforce, which we do use internally.

Any suggestions?  Is there a way to set the header options at the page or site level?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a javascript function to check whether it's being displayed in an iFrame.  Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't set the headers, you can get some javascript way early in the head of your page that will prevent the body from being visible if it's in an iframe:

this seems to be what all the cool kids are doing these days:

```
<style id="antiClickjack">body{display:none !important;}</style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        if (self === top) {
            var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
            antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
        } else {
            top.location = self.location;
        }
        </script>
```

source: [owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet](http://owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 1):

The usual idea, and probably simplest solution, is to add something like this bit of javascript to the pages you want to "break out" of iframe situations:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top.location!= self.location) {
        top.location = self.location.href
    }
</script>
```

You'll probably want to use a VF component for this to get re-use and a single place to edit the code if you need to modify/enhance it.

Comment: J-I can definitely do that as a "better than nothing".  Anything without the xframe options is going to throw a flag on our security scans and all the javascript-based solutions have known exploits.  Exploits against your suggestion go back 3-4 years.

Comment: this seems to be what all the cool kids are doing these days: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks for the link -- I am now much more educated on the state of the art for clickjacking! Gosh I'm glad I don't have to deal with it very often :)

Comment: j--I posted what I found as a better answer for posterity.